# Weird Segmentation Fault When dynamically allocating Array

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am creating a shell for one of my programming classes. I have a commandLine class meant to parse the commands typed into the shell, and dynamically allocate argv and set argc according to the number of commands. For the life of me i cannot figure out why i'm getting a segmentation fault after dynamically allocating the array of pointers to arrays for argv.

This is the constructor for the class. If anybody has any idea why i might be getting this fault, I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

```
CommandLine::CommandLine(istream& in){
    char * userInput = new char[256];
    char * pointer = &userInput[0];

    char cmdStorage[128][32];
    int cmdLength = 0;
    int argCount = 0;
    in.getline(userInput,256);

    while(1)
    {
        if (*pointer == ' ' || *pointer == '\0')
        {
            if (cmdLength != 0)
                argCount++;

            cmdLength = 0;
            if (*pointer == '\0')
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            cmdStorage[argCount][cmdLength] = *pointer;
            cmdLength++;
        }

        pointer++;
    }

    *argv = (char *) calloc(argCount,sizeof(char*));


    for (int i = 0; i < argCount; i++)
    {
        argv[i] = (char *) calloc(33,sizeof(char));
        memcpy(argv[i],cmdStorage[i],sizeof(cmdStorage[i]));
    }
    argc = argCount;
}
```

Comment: You might try doing it the C++ way? Or are you set on C?

Comment: I think you meant `calloc(argCount,sizeof(char))` , `char` instead of `char*`.

Comment: Maybe not the problem, but you should be checking `cmdLength` is in range ; what input causes the segv?

Comment: Also: where is `argv` defined; has it been allocated and is writable?

Comment: `*argv = (char *) calloc(argCount,sizeof(char*));` --> `argv = (char **) calloc(argCount, sizeof(char*));`

Comment: Got it working! Thanks guys! BLUEPIXY was correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
memcpy(argv[i],cmdStorage[i],sizeof(cmdStorage[i]));
```

`sizeof(cmdStorage[i])` is `>` the size of block `argv[i]` points to.